# Full backup job failed after changing backup location

Tags: sql-server, backup, aws

In AG Environment, for the last 30 days, the daily Full backup job is failing for a few of the larger databases. The rest of the databases are getting through daily so far. We recently changed the backup location path to aws S3 UNC storage.

We are seeing error in the SQL Server error log as:

> The operating system returned the error '59(An unexpected network error occurred.)' while attempting 'DiskChangeFileSize' on

How should we interpret the error message?

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue with the UNC storage. OS Error 59 = "An unexpected network error has occurred." In this case, since you're going to AWS, it's entirely possible there are transient network issues that the backup stream doesn't like. If you change it locally does it work without issue?

Comment: I just edited your question to make it more readable. I hope I understand your correctly, that your larger databases are failing to back up, whereas your smaller databases are being backed up without any issues? If not please feel free to [rollback](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/233222/revisions) my revision.

Comment: Earlier it was routed in local drive then Full backup job running successfully and  to save cost , moved to aws S3 storage.